# Case Statement left and right of character string SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to compose a case statement to output either to the left or right of "---"
This could be any number of characters before or after the ---,
I have used the below example for simplicity.

```
my productdescription = aaa---bbb

CASE WHEN productid = 'atbl%' THEN OUTPUT everything TO the LEFT OF "---"  from the productdescription  ( so OUTPUT aaa)

WHEN productid = 'atbr%' THEN OUTPUT everything TO the RIGHT OF "---" from the productdescription  ( so OUTPUT bbb)

ELSE ''

END AS leftright
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This isn't really what SQL is good at. You might have more success parsing candidates in application code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the operator `LIKE` and not `=` (unless your `productid` actually contains `%`).
For **MySql**:
Use the function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
CASE 
  WHEN productid LIKE 'atbl%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(productdescription, '---', 1)
  WHEN productid LIKE 'atbr%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(productdescription, '---', -1)
  ELSE ''
END AS leftright
```

If you are using **SQL Server** use `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` and `CHARINDEX()`:

```
CASE 
  WHEN productid LIKE 'atbl%' THEN LEFT(productdescription, CHARINDEX('---', productdescription) - 1)
  WHEN productid LIKE 'atbr%' THEN RIGHT(productdescription, LEN(productdescription) - CHARINDEX('---', productdescription) - 2)
  ELSE ''
END AS leftright
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for the response. I receive an error SUBSTRING_INDEX is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: You tagged MySql, right? SUBSTRING_INDEX is a MySql function.

Comment: Apologies, shouldnt have